# Reading data from file and converting into JSON in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing

I have the file log.txt with following data:

```
{"__TIMESTAMP":"2020-07-09T19:05:20.858013","__LABEL":"web_channel","__LEVEL":4,"__DIAGNOSE_SLOT":"","msg":"Port web_channel/diagnose_client not connected!"}
{"__TIMESTAMP":"2020-07-09T19:05:21.229737","__LABEL":"context_logging_addon","__LEVEL":4,"__DIAGNOSE_SLOT":"","msg":"startup component"}
{"__TIMESTAMP":"2020-07-09T19:05:21.229761","__LABEL":"context_logging_addon","__LEVEL":4,"__DIAGNOSE_SLOT":"","msg":"activate component"}
{"__TIMESTAMP":"2020-07-09T19:05:21.229793","__LABEL":"context_monitoring_addon","__LEVEL":4,"__DIAGNOSE_SLOT":"","msg":"startup component"}
{"__TIMESTAMP":"2020-07-09T19:05:21.229805","__LABEL":"context_monitoring_addon","__LEVEL":4,"__DIAGNOSE_SLOT":"","msg":"activate component"}
```

If I define a single row, I can convert in real JSON type:

```
import json
import datetime
from json import JSONEncoder

log = {
    "__TIMESTAMP":"2020-07-09T19:05:21.229737",
    "__LABEL":"context_logging_addon",
    "__LEVEL":4,
    "__DIAGNOSE_SLOT":"",
    "msg":"Port web_channel/diagnose_client not connected!"}

class DateTimeEncoder(JSONEncoder):
        #Override the default method
        def default(self,obj):
            if isinstance(obj,(datetime.date,datetime.datetime)):
                return obj.isoformat()

print("Printing to check how it will look like")
print(DateTimeEncoder().encode(log))
```

I have the following output, which format is perfect JSON.

```
Printing to check how it will look like
{"__TIMESTAMP": "2020-07-09T19:05:21.229737", "__LABEL": "context_logging_addon", "__LEVEL": 4, "__DIAGNOSE_SLOT": "", "msg": "Port web_channel/diagnose_client not connected!"}
```

But I don't know how should I open the log.txt file, read the data to convert into JSON without any failure.

Could you help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say your log.txt file is in the same directory than your .py file.
Just open it with `with open(...` and then parse your file according to your syntax to create a list of dictionaries (each item corresponding to a row, then parse each dictionary as you're currently doing).

Here is how you could open and parse your file:

```
with open("log.txt","r") as file:
    all_text = file.readlines()

parsed_line = list()
for text in all_text:
    parsed_line.append(dict([item.split('":"') for item in text[2:-2].split('","')]))
```

If you have any question about the parsing let me know. This one is pretty straightforward.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: I need more help, I get **ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required**  Error. What could be the problem?

Comment: The problem came from the parsing. To create a `dict` from the constructor you need to give it a list of list of 2 elements (e.g. [["a",3], ["b",6], ["c","hello"]]). However, the parsing was correct on my computer, I will check it back. Did you change the structure of your log.txt? I test my code with a copy/paste of your log.txt and all works well. Didn't you make any errors when copying the code? Could you send me the exact copy of your log.txt (or a least a portion that shows the structures)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I found the problem. My previous attempts have owerwrited my log file. Now the code works fine  :-). Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
logs = """[your log file above]"
for log in logs.splitlines():
    print(DateTimeEncoder().encode(log))
```

Output:

```
"{\"__TIMESTAMP\":\"2020-07-09T19:05:20.858013\",\"__LABEL\":\"web_channel\",\"__LEVEL\":4,\"__DIAGNOSE_SLOT\":\"\",\"msg\":\"Port web_channel/diagnose_client not connected!\"}"
"{\"__TIMESTAMP\":\"2020-07-09T19:05:21.229737\",\"__LABEL\":\"context_logging_addon\",\"__LEVEL\":4,\"__DIAGNOSE_SLOT\":\"\",\"msg\":\"startup component\"}"
   "{\"__TIMESTAMP\":\"2020-07-09T19:05:21.229761\",\"__LABEL\":\"context_logging_addon\",\"__LEVEL\":4,\"__DIAGNOSE_SLOT\":\"\",\"msg\":\"activate component\"}"
"{\"__TIMESTAMP\":\"2020-07-09T19:05:21.229793\",\"__LABEL\":\"context_monitoring_addon\",\"__LEVEL\":4,\"__DIAGNOSE_SLOT\":\"\",\"msg\":\"startup component\"}"
"{\"__TIMESTAMP\":\"2020-07-09T19:05:21.229805\",\"__LABEL\":\"context_monitoring_addon\",\"__LEVEL\":4,\"__DIAGNOSE_SLOT\":\"\",\"msg\":\"activate component\"}"
```

Comment: Could you give me more explanation? I don't understand clearly. I get **IndentationError: expected an indented block** Error.

Comment: @ZoltánDomokos Not sure; please edit your question and add the exact code that results in this error.